# How to programmatically change the background of grid layout?

Tags: android

```
public class TwoplayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GridLayout gridLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ---
    gridlayout= (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    gridLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boards2);
    }
}
```

This is not working.I think this works for other layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
gridLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boards2));
```

but it should work with `.setBackgroundResource(...)` too.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout

Comment: `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = (android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);`This worked. Thanks.